# What is the default PropertyChanged event's _invokationList

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged

I use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and it works well when property changes and change appears in design but I want to know how this happening?

Event is a delegate that invokes registered methods when it is triggered, so what method does `PropertyChanged` invoke?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQus2.jpg 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/33D4V.jpg

Comment: What exactly problem you are trying to solve by asking this question? How would knowing the answer help?

Comment: i need to know what's happening behind.

Answer (score 1):

If you use data binding in either WPF, Windows Forms or another UI technology, the framework itself will subscribe to the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event to monitor if one of your property is being changed. As soon as you raise the event, you essentially trigger the framework's code that will subsequently update any UI elements that you have bound to the property.